python web_page fuction returns invalid syntax
I am writing a simple webserver on a esp32 to control some leds.
def web_page(color_hex_data, brightness_data):
    html = f"""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>LED Control</title>
        <script>
            function updateColor(color) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "/color", true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send('color=' + encodeURIComponent(color.slice(1))); // Remove the '#' from color value
            }

            function updateBrightness(brightness) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "/brightness", true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send('brightness=' + encodeURIComponent(brightness));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>LED Control</h1>
        <input type="color" name="color" onchange="updateColor(this.value)" value="{color_hex_data}">
        <input type="range" name="brightness" min="0" max="255" step="1" onchange="updateBrightness(this.value)" value="{brightness_data}">
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    return html

This is the function in micropython and it returns an invalid syntax on return html, and I can't find the problem.
Its not the javascript. When I delete the f in html = f""" it works again, but I want to use the data color_hex_data and brightness_data in the inputs. The old function worked fine without the script with the usage of this data.
def web_page(color_hex, brightness):
    html = f"""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>LED Control</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>LED Control</h1>
    <form action="/color" method="post">
        <input type="color" name="color" value="{color_hex}">
        <input type="submit" value="Set Color">
    </form>
    <br>
    <form action="/brightness" method="post">
        <input type="range" name="brightness" min="0" max="255" step="1" value="{brightness}">
        <input type="submit" value="Set Brightness">
    </form>
</body>
</html>"""
    return html

color_hex_data and brightness_data are send in the correct way.
I am also not the brightest in java, so it might be really obvious.

What is the full error message you get from MicroPython? How about if you use the .format method instead of the f-string syntax?

The format option worked, thank you.
